# I'm getting acpi error while rebooting the linux os 23.04 and also suddenly my disk got full to 100% without any data

Tags: 23.04

I upgraded my linux os from 22.04 to 23.04 but suddenly disk got full and laptop started lagging. While rebooting it either on acpi_error page or dell symbol only but in elasticsearch it shows uptime. Please help me out with this

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Unfortunately, there is not enough specific information to go on here. All we know is that you have a Dell with some storage concerns. Could you [edit] your question to include: (1) whether this is Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server (2) whether the upgrade completed or failed (3) whether you have used a Live USB to boot the machine to examine the disk for files that can be deleted or not. With this, it may be possible to offer some suggestions 